# Python Django edit data in database by forms (django v.1.9.4)

Tags: forms, python-3.x, templates, django-forms, html-table

My goal is add data to database via form and make them editable via edit form.

My error:

> Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /testtable/car/new/
>       Exception Value: Reverse for 'car_list' with arguments '()' and keyword  arguments '{'pk': 2}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

and next problem is how to make a link to edit data
in template/car_list.html to car_edit.html.

```
<td><a href=>Edit</a> <a href="">Delete</a></td>
<td><a href="{% url 'tabletest:car_edit' pk=car.pk %}">Edit</a> <a href="">Delete</a></td>
```

When I type manually in Explorer http://localhost:8000/testtable/car/1/ it works, I see details of first article in database, but forms with pk arguments doesnt work.

MyApp/testtable/models.py

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class TableParemeters(models.Model):
     author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
     car_brand = models.CharField(max_length=20)
     car_type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
     car_colour = models.CharField(max_length=20)
     car_fuel = models.CharField(max_length=20)
     car_trans = models.CharField(max_length=20)
     car_license_plate = models.CharField(max_length=20)
     created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

def __str__(self):
    return "%s %s" % (self.car_brand, self.car_type)
```

MyApp/testtable/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, get_object_or_404, render_to_response, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.template import loader
from django.views import generic
from django.utils import timezone
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from .models import TableParemeters
from .forms import CarForm

def car_list(request):
    cars = TableParemeters.objects.all().order_by('id')
    return render(request, 'testtable/car_list.html', {'cars': cars})

def car_detail(request, pk):
    car = get_object_or_404(TableParemeters, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'testtable/car_detail.html', {'car': car})

def car_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CarForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            car = form.save(commit=False)
            car.save()
            return redirect ('car_list', pk=car.pk)
    else:
         form = CarForm()
    return render(request, 'testtable/car_new.html', {'form': form})            

def car_edit(request, pk):
    car = get_object_or_404(TableParemeters, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CarForm(request.POST, instance=car)
        if form.is_valid():
            car = formsave(commit=False)
            car.save()
            return redirect('car_detail', pk=car.pk)
    else:
         form = CarForm(instance=car)
    return render(request, 'testtable/car_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

MyApp/testtable/forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import TableParemeters

class CarForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model = TableParemeters
        fields = '__all__'
```

MyApp/testtable/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views

app_name = 'testtable'

urlpatterns = [
     #login
     #url(r'^$', views.login_page, name='login'),
     #logout
     #carlist url
    url(r'^$', views.car_list, name='car_list'),
     #detail car url
    url(r'^car/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.car_detail, name='car_detail'),
     #add new car to list url
    url(r'^car/new/$', views.car_new, name='car_new'),
     #edit car in the list
    url(r'^car/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$', views.car_edit, name='car_edit'),
    ]
```

MyApp/testtable/template/testtable/car_list.html

```
{% extends 'testtable/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Brand</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Colour</th>
        <th>Fuel</th>
        <th>Transmition</th>
        <th>License Plate</th>
        <th>Created Date</th>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>        
{% for testtable in cars %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ testtable.car_id }}</a></td>
        <td>{{ testtable.car_brand }}</a></td>
        <td>{{ testtable.car_type }}</td>
        <td>{{ testtable.car_colour }}</td>
        <td>{{ testtable.car_fuel }}</td>
        <td>{{ testtable.car_trans }}</td>
        <td>{{ testtable.car_license_plate }}</td>
        <td>{{ testtable.created_date }}</td>
        <td>{{ testtable.author }}</td>
        <td><a href=>Edit</a> <a href="">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>    
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean, that car_list not need pk and django can't found any url for car_list with parameter.
Maybe you can try replace line:
return redirect ('car_list', pk=car.pk)
with:
return redirect ('car_list')